# Can't change viewmodel value to empty

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

I have problem with my ViewModel in WPF app.
It does change property of PullingOrganization when value isn't empty, but when it's empty it will keep original value. It reaches the setter but for some reason value isn't updated.

XAML page:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Naam van organisatie" Style="{StaticResource LabelInputField}"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="inputOrganizationName" Text="{Binding OrganizationName}" Margin="0 5"/>
```

Specific viewModel class:

```
public class OrganizationAddWindowModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private PullingOrganization organization;

        public string OrganizationName
        {
            get { return organization.Name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != organization.Name)
                {
                    organization.Name = value;
                    OnPropertyChange("OrganizationName");
                }
            }
        }
        public string OrganizationLogo
        {
            get { return organization.Logo; }
            set
            {
                if (value != organization.Logo)
                {
                    organization.Logo = value;
                    OnPropertyChange("OrganizationLogo");
                }
            }
        }

        public PullingOrganization Organization 
        {
            get { return this.organization; }
        }

        public OrganizationAddWindowModel()
        {
            WindowTitle = "Truckpulling - Nieuwe organisatie";
            organization = new PullingOrganization();
        }
    }
```

General view model class.

```
 public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                //PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private string windowTitle;

        public string WindowTitle
        {
            get { return windowTitle; }
            set
            {
                if(windowTitle != value)
                {
                    windowTitle = value;
                    OnPropertyChange("WindowTitle");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that `OrganizationName` is not set to an empty string when you clear the `TextBox` or what is your issue?

Comment: How did you configure the binding between View and ViewModel?

Comment: @mm8 Yes that's what I mean